# command running through command prompt but not through batch file

Tags: batch-file, command

I want to rename the network interface name and wrote the script mentioned below but I am getting the error while running the script but if I run the command directly on command prompt it is working fine

Script:

```
@echo off
netsh interface set interface name="Conexión de área local 2" newname="ethernet"
pause
```

***Error Received:***

> An interface with this name is not registered with the router.

command to see the network interface names:

```
netsh interface show interface
```

***output:***

> Conexión de área local 2

Comment: The exact commands are now reflecting in my question

Comment: already done... no effect

Answer (score 0):

The above problem arises because of encoding problem in batch file. it is not able to encode the accented characters..

I found the solution of above problem. The working script is:

```
    @echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:." %%x in ('chcp') do set cp=%%x
chcp 1252>nul

netsh interface set interface name="Conexión de área local 2" newname="ethernet"

chcp %cp%>nul
```